# NextJS is not stylizing div after adding new class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, next.js

I am coding this front-end with NextJS framework and after the user clicks the target button, a class will be added to a specific div. This class is supposed to change the div style, once I had added unique styles to this class in my css file.

The original element:

```
<div class="Home_wordBlockWrapper__nwyZO" id="generated-block"><h3>C</h3></div>
```

The element after clicking the button:

```
<div class="Home_wordBlockWrapper__nwyZO filled rightindex" id="generated-block"><h3>C</h3></div>
```

CSS File:

```
.wordBlockWrapper {
  border: 2px solid rgb(226, 232, 240); 
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.wordBlockWrapper {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  transition: .5 ease-in-out;
}

.filled {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

The problem is: Though the class is added, the div style remains the same. Do you guys know where is the error?

Comment: I can see that your CSS has two `.wordBlockWrapper`

Comment: I changed those two elements into one. But, I still having the issue

Comment: Can you show us how you're adding the class to the element? It looks like you're adding a global CSS class and not the scoped CSS module class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I doesn't solved my question with an usual way. But, anyway, my solution was: Instead of trying to add a class to the element and then after stylizing it in the css file, I added a JS script to add the styles in the document element, getting it by its id.

Solution:

```
var tb = document.getElementsByClassName(styles.wordBlockWrapper)[matching.index]
var targBlockId = document.getElementById(tb.id);
  
if(targBlockId !== null) {
    targBlockId.style.backgroundColor = "#13d178"
    targBlockId.style.color = "#fff"
}
```

This way, the issue is solved adding the styles with a JS script, instead of adding a class to its classList and then stylizing it with css files.